# Statistical Tests for machine learning performances

Tags: statistics

I have two sets of machine learning outputs. Test A and Test B (paired).

I have done t.test to find statiscal difference between the two.

I am trying to find best set and could do mean score of all - but are there any other tests that can compared outcomes to conclude which one is better?

[image]

recommendation of tests..

Comment: What is the best set or what is better in that question? You can for instance check via standard statistical estimates (moments like mean and variance) if both tests exhibit similar properties.

Comment: what gives a better result?